# No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure

Tags: dpkg

I was trying to install PDF Acrobat in ubuntu 14.04. I used the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

After that I came with this error:

```
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mpm-itk (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2-mpm-itk:
 apache2-mpm-itk depends on libapache2-mpm-itk; however:
  Package libapache2-mpm-itk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apache2-mpm-itk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of koha-common:
 koha-common depends on apache2-mpm-itk; however:
  Package apache2-mpm-itk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package koha-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up acroread-bin (9.5.5-1precise1) ...
Setting up acroread (9.5.5-1precise1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No LSB modules are available.
No LSB modules are available.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mpm-itk
 apache2-mpm-itk
 koha-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not a problem with the installation of `acroread`. Check your `*.list` files with the command below

```
grep -Pr '^deb(\-src)*.+debian\.koha-community\.org\/koha' /etc/apt/ | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

Example output

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/koha.list
```

1. Remove the shown file via, eg

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/koha.list
   ```
2. Some housekeeping

   ```
   sudo apt-get clear
   ```
3. Remove `koha-common`

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove koha-common
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
4. Install `acroread`

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall acroread
   ```
5. **If you still need** `koha`, add the `koha` repository again and install

   ```
   echo deb http://debian.koha-community.org/koha stable main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/koha.list
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install koha-common
   ```